# How do you set a variable from an input in a module

Tags: module, python-3.4

So, I'm trying to set a variable in my main program to an integer input from a function in a module. I can't work out how to do this.

This is my main program. Menu is the name of my module, as I'm using it to display a menu. 'menulist' is where you say what you want the menu to display. That part works OK.

```
import time, sys
from menu import *

menulist = ['Say hi', 'Say bye', 'Say yes', 'Say no', 'Exit']
choice = int(0)
menu(menulist)

choosing(menulist, choice)

print(choice) ##This is so I can see what it is
if choice == 1:
    print('Say hi')
elif choice == 2:
    print('Say bye')
elif choice == 3:
    print('Say yes')
elif choice == 4:
    print('Say no')
elif choice == 5:
    sys.exit()
else: ##This will print if choice doesn't equal what I want
    print('Error')
```

This is my module.

```
import time

def menu(menulist):
    print('Menu:')
    time.sleep(1)
    x = 0
    while x < len(menulist):
        y = x + 1
        printout = '     ' + str(y) + '. ' + menulist[x]
        print(printout)
        x = x + 1
        time.sleep(0.3)
    time.sleep(0.7)
    print('')


def choosing(menulist, choice):
    flag = True
    while flag:
        try:
            choice = int(input('Enter the number of your choice: '))
            time.sleep(0.8)
            if choice < 1 or choice > len(menulist):
                print('That wasn\'t an option sorry')
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                flag = False
        except ValueError:
            print('That wasn\'t an option sorry')
            time.sleep(1)
```

The menu function works fine, and the choosing function almost does what I want it to, but it won't set 'choice' in my main program to the input when I call it from my module. Sorry if it's something blatantly obvious, I'm pretty new to programming. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your module doesn't recognise `choice` as a global variable. Inside `def choosing(...)`, `choice` is simply a local variable that gets assigned the value of your input (converted to an `int`).
You do pass `choice` to `choosing`, but since you've set `choice` to `0` before that, it is an immutable variable, and Python has (behind the scenes) created a local copy. So for all matters, `choice` is a local variable inside `choosing`.

Once your program leaves the function `choosing`, the variable and its value simply disappear (for all practical purposes).

To solve this, you shouldn't attempt to make `choice` global: generally, that is bad design (plenty of exceptions, but still, don't).

Instead, you can simply return `choice` from the function, and assign it in your main program. Relevant part of your module:

```
def choosing(menulist):
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input('Enter the number of your choice: '))
            time.sleep(0.8)
            if choice < 1 or choice > len(menulist):
                print('That wasn\'t an option sorry')
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print('That wasn\'t an option sorry')
            time.sleep(1)
    return choice
```

(I made a slight alteration here: you can simply use the `break` statement to break out of the continous while loop, instead of the extra `flag` variable.)
Note: there is no need to assign an initial value to choice: the function is structured to it always has to pass through the line `choice = int(...`. That, or it exist with an exception other than `ValueError`.

The relevant part of your main program:

```
import time, sys
from menu import *

menulist = ['Say hi', 'Say bye', 'Say yes', 'Say no', 'Exit']
menu(menulist)

choice = choosing(menulist)
```

Together with my above note: no need for an initial value of `choice`.

Finally: see how `choice` has disappeared from the parameters in the function, both in the call to and the definition of `choosing`.

That last point suggest to me that you might be coming from a different programming language. In Python, it is rare to pass a parameter to a function to have it altered. You simply return it, because that is easy and clearer. In you have multiple variables to alter, you can for example return a tuple: `return a, b, c`. Or a dict, or whatever you fancy (but the tuple is the starting point for multiple return values).

Comment: Thanks so much. I am new to programming so I didn't really understand it all, but this does make a lot more sense. I was messing around I but to try to get it to work, hence things like initialising choice. Thanks again